# Mongodb use aggregate to iterate through collection

Tags: regex, mongodb, for-loop, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of summaries called **collectioname**, and an list of key words called **keywords**. 
I used below code filter out all the summaries in **collectioname** that contains the first key word in the list, and it worked great.

```
db.collectioname.aggregate([ { $match: { summary: {$regex: keywords[1], $options:"i"} } }, { $out: "subsetfinal" } ]);
```

But when I started to loop it, it gave me aggregation error. I really can't figure out why.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 79; i++) {db.collectioname.aggregate([ { $match: { summary: {$regex: keywords[i], $options:"i"} } }, { $out: "subsetfinal" } ])};
```

it gives me error:

$regex has to be a string
code 16810

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pipe-delimited regex pattern with the keywords like this:

**Test documents:**

```
db.collectioname.insert([
    { summary: "a b c" },
    { summary: "d e f" },
    { summary: "g h i" },
    { summary: "j k l" },
    { summary: "m n o" }
]);
```

**The magic:**

```
var keywords = ["a", "d", "j"],
    regex = keywords.join("|");

db.collectioname.aggregate([ 
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "summary": {
                "$regex": regex, 
                "$options": "i"
            } 
        } 
    }, 
    { "$out": "subsetfinal" } 
]);
```

**The query:**

```
db.subsetfinal.find({}, {_id:0})
```

gives

```
/* 0 */
{
    "summary" : "a b c"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "summary" : "d e f"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "summary" : "j k l"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with forEach:

```
keywords.forEach(function(keyword)
 { 
    db.collectioname.aggregate([ { $match: { summary: {$regex: keyword, $options:"i"} } }, { $out: "subsetfinal" } ])
});
```

Comment: strange, it gives zero output but summary[1] is 581, I think aggregate might not work as I think it would work. It overwrites the odd data, iteration will not work with it.